# How do I save a Java long value to file?

Tags: java, json, eclipse, long-integer, twitter4j

So iv'e been trying to find a way of saving a "long" value to a file. I'm using the Twitter4j packages. When I get a list of Followers IDs, it saves them into a long variable. I can do a System Out Print of the value, but I can't write it to a file. I'll show it in the code.

```
//First of course I put all this stuff in. This is not the Problem though.
String consumerKey = "************"; 
String consumerSecret = "**************";
String accessToken = "*******************************";
String accessTokenSecret = "*****************";
TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory();
Twitter twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken, accessTokenSecret));

//Then add the cursor value and call the command
long cursor = -1;                
IDs ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs("username_foo",cursor);

//If I want to the next cursor value
System.out.print(ids.getNextCursor());

//It works to do a system out print of the IDs
for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {System.out.println(id);}

//So how do I write it into a file? This sure don't work.
file.write(getIDs());
```

Just in case you are wondering, I am using FileOutputStream and DataOutputSream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write it line wise to a plain text file, use a `BufferedWriter` and write each line of the values like so:

```
File outputFile = new File("/path/to/file.txt");
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(outputFile), "UTF-8"));
for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
    writer.write(id + "\n");
}
writer.close();
```

(a `DataOutputStream` in contrast will not give you a human-readable format).

Comment: Ok, I'll try this. And yes, the DataOutputStream is returning odd symbols.

Comment: @TysonU That's what DataOutputStream is supposed to do.

Comment: @Boann The Data output stream was just a method I was trying to use to save and append the file.

Comment: @qqilihq Its giving me this error: The method write(int) is in the type Writer is not applicable for the arguments (Long). Any ideas?

Comment: @TysonU And? That's fine, DataOutputStream can "save and append the file". If you want text, use a Writer, if you want binary, use a DataOutputStream, but don't blame DataOutputStream for being "odd" if you choose the thing you don't want.

Comment: @TysonU As to the error with the Writer code, it doesn't have a `write(long)` method, so change `write(value)` to `write("" + value)`, (or instead use a PrintWriter or PrintStream and use its `print` methods).

Comment: Ok. This works. writer.write(value + "\n"); I thought that it didn't work at first but it was just notepad not showing it properly. Should I Update the post with this method I used? It might help same other noobs like me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that 'file' is your `DataOutputStream`:

```
for (long id : ids.getIDs()) file.writeLong(id);
```